# write like condition with or_where clause in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my controller. I want solution for Following query ,

```
      $this->datatables ->select('e.emp_id')
            ->select('CONCAT(e.first_name," ",e.middle_name," ",e.last_name) as name',FALSE)
            ->select('e.contact_no,e.dob,e.designation,e.email_id,e.short_address,e.landmark,a.po_region_name,a.state')
                              ->add_column('Edit ',' <a href="'.site_url().'/employee/edit_employee/$1" class="fa fa-pencil icons"></a>| <a href="'.site_url().'/employee/delete_employee/$1" class="fa fa-trash-o icons"></a>', 'e.emp_id')
                             ->from('employee e')
                         ->join('address_pin_details a','a.uid=e.address_detail_id')

                            ->where('e.emp_id',$emp_id)
                            ->or_where("CONCAT(e.first_name, ' ', e.middle_name,' ',e.last_name) LIKE '%$fname%'", NULL, FALSE)
                            ->or_where('e.email_id',$email_id)
                            ->or_where('a.po_region_name',$city)
                            ->or_where('e.contact_no',$contact_no)
                            ->where('e.is_active',1);




In this query only one search name condition work properly can you help me to work all search conditions correctly. we want like condition for searching concatenation of first name, last name, middle name.
```

Thanks In Advance !

Comment: Is emp_id condition is working ?

Comment: No.. emp_id is also not working

Comment: only name condition was working others are not working

Comment: Which name condition CONCAT one

Comment: yes concat condition if remove concat where condition then other conditions are works

Comment: Using $this->db->last_query() print your query.You have problem in CONCAT condition which is adding backticks to query which is making it unusable.

Comment: after removing backticks still not working.